# How to drop rows based on multiple condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have the following **datframe setup**:

```
dic = {'customer_id': [102, 102, 105, 105, 110, 110, 111], 
       'product':['skateboard', 'skateboard', 'skateboard', 'skateboard', 'shoes', 'skateboard', 'skateboard'],
       'brand': ['Vans', 'Converse', 'Vans', 'Converse', 'Converse','Converse', 'Vans'],
      'membership': ['member', 'not-member', 'not-member', 'not-member', 'member','not-member', 'not-member']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

**Requirement:** I need to drop rows where membership 'not-member' at customer_id and product granularity if the customer is a 'member' of any brand.

For example, in the above dataframe, we drop customer '102' with product 'skateboard' where membership is 'not-member' because they are already a member of a brand (Vans). We do not drop 105 because they are not a member of any brand. We do not drop 110 because the products are different.

So, the output should look like the following:
[image]

**My approach:** First to make a list of unique customer_id + product (ex: 102_skateboard). Then loop over the list, then filter out the dataframe on unique customer-product pairs, then check if the dataframe contains membership, if true then drop not-member rows. This gives me the expected output but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

```
df['customer_product'] = df['customer_id'].astype(str) + '_' + df['product']
unique_customer_product = df['customer_product'].unique()
for pair in unique_customer_product:
    filtered_df = df[df['customer_product'] == pair]
    if 'member' in filtered_df['membership'].values:
        df = df.drop(df[(df.customer_product == pair) & (df.membership == 'not-member')].index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a helper boolean column `is_member` and then it's pretty straighforward to express the condition.

```py
df['is_member'] = df.membership.eq('member')
drop_mask = (
    ~df['is_member']
    & df.groupby(['customer_id', 'product'])['is_member'].transform('any')
)
df = df.loc[~drop_mask].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=["customer_id", "product", "brand", "membership"])

df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.loc[df["customer_id"] == idx, :].drop_duplicates(["product"], keep="last")
        if not df.loc[df["customer_id"] == idx, :]
        .drop_duplicates(["product"], keep="last")
        .pipe(lambda df_: df_.loc[df_["membership"] == "member", :])
        .empty
        else df.loc[df["customer_id"] == idx, :]
        for idx in df["customer_id"].unique()
    ],
).sort_values(["customer_id", "brand"], ascending=[True, False], ignore_index=True)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
   customer_id     product     brand  membership
0          102  skateboard      Vans      member
1          105  skateboard      Vans  not-member
2          105  skateboard  Converse  not-member
3          110       shoes  Converse      member
4          110  skateboard  Converse  not-member
5          111  skateboard      Vans  not-member
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['row'] = True


def my_func(x):
    aaa = x[x['membership'] == 'not-member']
    if len(x[x['membership'] == 'member']) > 0 and len(aaa) > 0:
        df.loc[aaa.index, 'row'] = False


df.groupby(['customer_id', 'product']).apply(my_func)

df = df[df['row']].reset_index().drop(['index', 'row'], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output

```
   customer_id     product     brand  membership
0          102  skateboard      Vans      member
1          105  skateboard      Vans  not-member
2          105  skateboard  Converse  not-member
3          110       shoes  Converse      member
4          110  skateboard  Converse  not-member
5          111  skateboard      Vans  not-member
```

Here is where the 'row' helper column is created. Rows are [grouped](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns 'customer_id', 'product', rows are passed to [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), which calls the my_func function. There is a check in the function: there must be values 'not-member' and 'member'. If so, use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to set False for "not a member".